# Removing backslash coming in the string

Tags: python

I'm creating a dictionary for which one of the value is a string with backslash,I know that python is automatically adding escape sequence.But at the end when you print the dictionary it's still printing that value with muliple backslashes,Now i have to pass this dictionary to another tool which is not expecting multiple backslashes,So currently I'm forced to manually remove a backslash is there a way to remove the backslash from the value of dictionary automatically.

```
(Pdb) print value2
"\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"
(Pdb) value2
'"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'
```

Comment: The string value seems to be `value2 = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"` (contains 5 characters having the *ASCII* codes from 1 to 5). The 2nd form seems just a `repr(value2)`.

Comment: @CristiFati: no, these are literal backslashes. That's why they are shown when using *`print`*, and the `repr()` shows the literal value with the slashes doubled.

Comment: You **do not have a value with double backslashes**. The `repr()` output gives you valid Python syntax to recreate the value. There is no problem here, you have the value you need, just pass it on.

Comment: For your understanding: a double backslash is the technical representation of a single backslash and `\x01` is the technical representation of a byte with value 01 (hex). This is called escape sequences.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah right, I was typing `value2` instead of `print(value2)`.

Comment: Try printing individual characters. If there *are* double backslashes, then both `print value2[0]` and `print value2[1]` would print a backslash. But you'll get `\` and `x` printed, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing string *representations* with string *values*.

When you echo a string object in the Python interpreter, the output is really produced by printing the result of the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr). This function outputs *debugging friendly representations*, and for strings, that representation is valid Python syntax you can copy and paste back into Python.

`print` on the other hand, just writes the actual value in the string to the terminal. That's rather different from the Python syntax that creates the value. A backslash in the string *prints* as a backslash, you wouldn't see a backslash if there wasn't one in the value.

In Python string literal syntax, the `\` backslash character has special meaning, it's the first character of an *escape sequence*. So if you want to have an actual backslash in the *value* of the string, you would need to use `\\` to 'escape the escape'. There is other syntax where the backslash would not have special meaning, but the `repr()` representation of a string doesn't use that other syntax. So it'll output *any backslash in the value* as the escape sequence `\\`.

That doesn't mean that the value has two backslashes. It just means that you can copy the output, and paste it into Python, and it'll *produce the same string value*.

You can see that your string value doesn't have double backslashes by looking at individual characters:

```
>>> value2 = '"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'
>>> value2
'"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'
>>> print value2
"\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"
>>> print value2[0]
"
>>> print value2[1]
\
>>> print value2[2]
x
>>> value2[0]
'"'
>>> value2[1]
'\\'
>>> value2[2]
'x'
```

Printing `value2[1]` shows that that single character is a backslash. *Echoing* that single character shows `'\\'`, the Python syntax to recreate a string with a single character.

When you echo dictionaries or lists or other standard Python containers, they too are echoed using valid Python syntax, so their contents all are shown by using `repr()` on them, including strings:

```
>>> d = {'foo': value2}
>>> d
{'foo': '"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'}
```

Again, that's not the *value*, that's the *representation* of the string contents.

On top of that, container types have no *string value*, so printing a dictionary or list or other standard container type will only ever show their representation:

```
>>> print d  # shows a dictionary representation
{'foo': '"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'}
>>> print d['foo']   # shows the value of the d['foo'] string
"\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"
```

You'd have to print individual values (such as `d['foo']` above), or create your own string value from the components (which involves accessing all the contents and building a new string from that). Containers are not meant to be end-user-friendly values, so Python doesn't provide you with a string value for them either.

Strings can also contain non-printable characters, characters that don't have a human-readable value, such as a newline, or a tab character, and even the BELL character that'll make most terminals go *beep* when you write one of those to them. And in Python 2, the `str` type holds bytes, really, and only printable characters in the ASCII range (values 00 - 7F) considered when producing the `repr()` output. Anything outside is *always* considered unprintable, even if you could decode those bytes as Latin-1 or another commonly used codec.

So when you *do* have special characters other than `\` in the string, you'd see this in the representation:

```
>>> value_with_no_backslashes = "This is mostly ASCII with a \b bell and a newline:\nSome UTF-8 data: "
>>> print value_with_no_backslashes  # works because my terminal accepts UTF-8
This is mostly ASCII with a bell and a newline:
Some UTF-8 data: 
>>> value_with_no_backslashes
'This is mostly ASCII with a \x08 bell and a newline:\nSome UTF-8 data: \xf0\x9f\xa6\x8a'
```

Now, when I echo the value, there are backslashes, to make sure the non-printable characters can easily be copied and reproduce the same value again. Note that those backslashes are *not doubled* in the echoed syntax.

Note that representations are *Python specific* and should only be used to aid debugging. Writing them to logs is fine, using them to pass values between programs is not. Always use a serialisation format to communicate between programs, including command-line tools started as subprocesses or by writing output to the terminal. Python comes with [JSON support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) built in, and for Python-to-Python serialisation with no chance of third-party interference, [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) can be used for almost any Python data structure.

Comment: I'm passing value for value2 from an excel sheet where i had passed as "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05" but python interprets it as (Pdb) (Pdb) value2
'"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'
(Pdb) new_d={'apple':value2}
(Pdb) new_d
{'apple': '"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'}

Comment: (Pdb) print new_d
{'apple': '"\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05"'}

Comment: @Ashwinkumar: that's explained in my answer. You are printing the dictionary, and dictionaries have no `str()` string conversion, only a `repr()` representation. Printing the dictionary will show the representation. `print new_d['apple']` to access *just* the string value.

Comment: Now it works here If i individually print a single item,My end task is to copy a dictionary of dictionaries where this value could be anywhere,And I have to pass that whole dictionary to another tool which doesn't accept double backslash.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, as usual; but isn't this a common enough question that there should be a canonical FAQ which this should be marked as a duplicate of?

Comment: @Ashwinkumar: Is that tool a Python library? Then you are just passing a dictionary object. Is that tool something else? Then that tool should not be passed a Python dictionary!  Read the documentation carefully, they probably accept JSON data instead, so use the `json` library to produce it. **Python syntax is not JSON syntax**, there are some fundamental differences even if they look a lot like the same thing.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar: Put differently, **never** use Python container representations as a format to communicate with another tool. Use an explicit serialisation format. JSON is one such format, but there are others. For Python to Python communication where you don't have to worry about untrusted third-party interference, consider using `pickle`, for example.

Comment: @tripleee: I always look for such a dupe, and can never find a good one. I wrote this one because I got fed up with looking. Perhaps this one can be the canonical.